# Polymorphic function that splits list or string at specific intervals

Tags: haskell

How can I split a list into sublists at specific values? For example:

```
Main>split [1,2,3,0,4,5,0,0,7,8,9] 0
[[1,2,3],[4,5],[7,8,9]]
Main>split "Mary had a little lamb" ' '
["Mary","had","a","little","lamb"]
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65322327/polymorphic-function-that-splits-list-string-at-specific-intervals

Comment: StackOverflow is *not* a homework service. Make a fair attempt and come back
with *specific* questions about that attempt. See the
[*open letter to students with homework problems*](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, It's not a duplicate man, my friend tried to ask the question but you locked him out so I reworked it into a smaller task for him so he doesn;t have to wait another 90 minutes and so it doesn't violate the terms of being a "homework service"

Comment: (1) this is homework without an attempt. (2) as the [meta page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) says "*Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. If we can't see enough work on your part your question will likely be booed off the stage; it will be voted down and closed.*" (3) the only difference is that `lsplit` is not `split` (for the rest it is a verbatim copy); (4) likely this violates the academic integrity terms of you school?

Answer (score 1):

If you search [hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/) for the signature of the function you're looking for, it might give you a lot of useful results. Maybe the function you're looking for is one of those...

Based on your two examples, the signature you're looking for is

```hs
[a] -> a -> [[a]]
```

If you search for that, you'll see some functions with the name containing *`split`*, and the signature similar to that, namely `a -> [a] -> [[a]]`, which means they just expect the two arguments in the flipped order.